# How to convert LocalDateTime from one format to another

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```java
String time1 = "2019-08-08T09:17:31.795306";
LocalDateTime localDateTime3 = LocalDateTime.parse(time1);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String format2 = localDateTime3.format(formatter); // I want here to return LocalDateTime instead of String
System.out.println(format2);
```

I just want to format LocalDateTime from one format to another and return LocalDateTime, not String (this is needed for my business logic).

Comment: The date is `localDateTime3` - just use another formatter

Comment: First things first, a `LocalDateTime` will not yield the timezone information. Secondly, it will not yield any string format either, hence `format` returning `String`.

Comment: There is not time zone of offset in the `String time1`, which seems to make `LocalDateTime` a good match. What I don't get is, why don't you `return localDateTime3;` if you want to return a `LocalDateTime` rather than a `String`? A `DateTimeFormatter` is only needed when you want a `String` of a specific format. A `LocalDateTime` does not have a format itself, it only stores temporal units.

Comment: @deHaar Does LocalDateTime have itself for my format as well ? (dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss).

Comment: **Important**: a `LocalDateTime` itself does not have a format. All it has, is a default textual representation of it, returned by the `toString()` method.

Comment: It **does not have any format**, you can pass around `LocalDateTime`s and only format them where a `String` of a specific format is needed, e.g. in a GUI or a log file. At the point where you want to print the `LocalDateTime`, you apply the desired `DateTimeFormatter`, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

## Text has a format; date-time objects do not

Date-time objects do not have a “format”. They have an internally-defined representation of their assigned value.

Text can be said to have a format. But a date-time object is not text. **`LocalDateTime` is not text.**

### Text to object

When you want to produce a `LocalDateTime` object to represent a value communicated textually, use `LocalDateTime.parse` method. If the text is not in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, you’ll also need a `DateTimeFormatter` object to assist in parsing.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-08-08T09:17:31.795306" ) ;
```

### Object to text

When you want to produce text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `LocalDateTime#toString`. To produce text in other formats, call `LocalDateTime#format` while passing a `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
String output = ldt.toString() ;
```

> 2019-08-08T09:17:31.795306